# Audio not playing in Howler.js

Tags: javascript, html, audio, howler.js

I'm trying to play sounds through Howler but it's not working. No audio is played and there is no error message being displayed in the console. The code is shown below.

```
var ngTest= new Howl({
    src:["https://www.newgrounds.com/audio/download/801982"]
    });

ngTest.play();
```

Comment: Are you testing on Chrome? If so, you can no longer play audio without first "unlocking" audio on the tab by playing from within a user action like a click.

Answer (score 0):

That URL is not friendly for streaming from newgrounds. Try to upload the mp3 in a different location. I tested by downloading the file locally and calling this code and it worked.

```
var ngTest= new Howl({
    src:["801982_Accentus.mp3"]
    });

ngTest.play();
```

Comment: Ok. Do you know of any other library that has the same features/functionality as howler then that I could use? I kinda need to grab songs like this because of how I'm going to integrate them. I already tried it with the default audio commands built into JavaScript and it loaded the sound fine, so I'm sure there's something out there that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

A live stream or MP3 URL can only be played through HTML5 Audio.

```
let file= new Howl({
        src: 'http://20423.live.streamtheworld.com/RADIO538.mp3',
        html5: true, // A live stream can only be played through HTML5 Audio.
        format: ['mp3', 'aac']
});

file.play();
```